# Update active navigation tab without animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-compat

I have implemented an infinite looping ViewPager following some guides online... basically i fake the number of item overriding the GetCount method of the adapter.

It works well, no problem there, fragments swipe smoothly... 
I have just one last issue left: my action bar is in tab navigation mode, so i would like its tab widget to be updated with the current active fragment, the problem is that if i update the active tab after the swipe with the "setSelectedNavigationItem" method, this triggers an animation... that look weird. 
I would like just to set the active tab so the widget properly shows what fragment is active without displaying the animation (that was already handed over by the rest of the code).

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {                      
                    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                            position % mPagerAdapter.getRealCount());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some case for default actionbar.

Tabs in actionbar is placed inside [ScrollingTabContainerView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java). When you select tab, animateToTab is called. And there smoothScrollTo is callied.

You can get this container via reflection. Somting like this (not shure in my java):

```
Field tabContainerField getActionBar().class.getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
tabContainerField.setAccessible(true);
HorizontalScrollView tabsScroll = (HorizontalScrollView)tabContainerField.get(getActionBar);
```

Than you can scroll container to proper position before select tab. As I can see, this code will work on [SupportActionBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.4_r0.7/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplBase.java) too.

Or you can create your own tabbar instead of using system.